# GWT FocusPanel clickHandler not working when created with a element

Tags: java, dom, gwt, dom-events

Hello fellow GWT folks.

In my usage of GWT, I'm having an issue with a FocusPanel not handling the clickEvent that is added to it.  I don't do GWT the standard way, ie building the GUI with UI binder or pure java code widgets.  My host GWT HTML file is 1 large file that has div tags that represent the 'pages' of content.  I use GWT to control the DOM.

I have this HTML that I'm importing as the contents of the FocusPanel.

```
<div id="editCardsResponses">
    <div id="editCardsSuccess" class="success-box clickable">
        <span id="editCardsSuccessLabel">Your card was successfully deleted/edit/added.</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

Here's the Code...

```
RootPanel editCardsSuccess = RootPanel.get("editCardsSuccess");
FocusPanel editCardsSuccessPanel = new FocusPanel(editCardsSuccess);
editCardsSuccessPanel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        hideWidget(editCardsSuccessPanel);
        }
    });
```

This didn't work until I did this...

```
final HTMLPanel editCardsSuccess = view.getEditCardsSuccess();
editCardsSuccess.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        hideWidget(editCardsSuccess);
    }
}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

I even tried adding the FocusPanel to the parent DIV, thinking that the FocusPanel wasn't attached to the DOM, but that also didn't work.

```
RootPanel.get("editCardsResponses").add(editCardsSuccessPanel);
```

I would like to use the FocusPanel, as GWT wants to add a hidden input the DOM, in addtion to the element it wraps.  I assume the hidden input handles some cross browser issue that I might lose if I just use the domHandler method.

Can anyone help explain why the FocusPanel.ClickHandler wouldn't be taking effect, but an attached domHandler would?

If DOM attachment is the problem, Is there a way to re-attach elements/widgets that were detached?

If I go with the domHandler way... what compatibility do I loose by not getting the hidden input that the GWT FocusPanel widget provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with adding a DOM handler the way you described. It will work across all browsers.

Comment: ahh good to know.  I read up some more and found that the added input is for key access: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/FocusImplStandard.java My use case doesn't need it so I'll stick with addDomHandler for now.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Add DOM `ONCLICK` handler event on the Element.

sample code:

```
final Element desc = RootPanel.get("editCardsSuccess").getElement();
DOM.sinkEvents((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, Event.ONCLICK);
DOM.setEventListener((com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) desc, new EventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event e) {
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(e)) {
            case Event.ONCLICK:
                System.out.println("click");
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This did work as well.  Thanks.  I like the addDomHandler method a little better as it seems cleaner.